# Странное поведение при сокрытии new

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

В общем. Есть у меня базовая моделька:

```
public class BaseReturn
{
    public object Model {get; set;}
}
```

Имеется его наследник:

```
public class BackendReturn : BaseReturn
{
    public BackendReturn() { }

    public BackendReturn(Attachment model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public new Attachment Model { get; private set; }
}
```

В нём с помощью new меняется возвращаемый тип.

А так же имеется возвращающий метод из контроллера:

```
    internal IActionResult File(BaseReturn attachment)
    {
        if (!attachment.Success)
            return GetError(attachment.Code, attachment.Message);

        var model = (attachment.Model as Attachment);

        return base.File((model.Stream as MemoryStream).ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", model.FileName);
    }
```

Проблема в том что почему-то model ссылается на базовый объект из BaseReturn -> object, а не на тот который реально передаётся (BackendReturn -> Attachment)
Я бы подумал, что я дурак сам. НО. Именно этот код у меня работал раньше. В другом проекте правда (который я тоже писал), но работало без проблем.

Значит, похоже, нужно что-то настроить... но вот что я не понимаю..
Кто может наставить на путь истинный?

Comment: потому что attachment - это базовый тип и у него совершенно другое свойство нежели в производном. делайте (attachment as BackendReturn).Model

Comment: к слову лучше сделайте virtual свойство

Comment: @Aarnihauta attachment это мой тип созданный мной же.
Проблема с virtual в том что override нельзя менять возвращаемый тип.
Моя же идея что я делаю нетипизацию без явного указания что это нетипизированное.

Comment: Используйте Generic Types, а не `new`

Comment: Смысла в абстракциях здесь нет, так как метод `File` использует конкретные типы. И если в `BaseReturn attachment` будет передан не `BackendReturn` а другой наследник - все сломается. Правильные абстракции - это когда не ломается.